# how to navigate from a content page to the second tab of Tabbed page in xamarin.forms using Prism

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism

once user click on the search bar he/she directs to a model content page and after searching and selecting the search result. I want user to redirect to the second tab of a tabbed page. 
is this possible using prism ?

Answer (score 0):

Navigation for `TabbedPage`s has been improved with Prism 7. Please see the blog post [here](http://brianlagunas.com/whats-new-in-prism-for-xamarin-forms-7-0/)

> `NavigateAsync(“TabbedPage?selectedTab=MiddleTab/ViewA/ViewB”)`
>
> This will navigate to the TabbedPage, selected the `MiddleTab` and continue navigating `ViewA` and `ViewB` onto the navigation stack.

The blog post ist not 100% clear, but don't take `MiddleTab` literally. Most likely this will be the class name of a view added to the `TabbedPage`.